# How to spawn a new node from inside C++ code

Tags: ros, node, roscpp, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the gazebo_ros package, which is an interface for using ROS with the Gazebo simulation software. On their [relevant documentation page](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_comm&cat=connect_ros#SpawnModel), they say that the best way to dynamically create a new model in the simulation is to run the node for spawning models:

```
rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -database coke_can -sdf -model coke_can3 -y 2.2 -x -0.3
```

This node functions as a wrapper that will get XML from the database and load it, etc. My question is, is there a way to run this node with the command above, but from the C++ code of an already-running ROS node? i.e. to add models dynamically, once the controller node is already running.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207007/how-to-spawn-a-new-node-from-inside-c++-code/) by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In light of no better answer being given, I'll show my hacky workaround. It was as simple as just using the `system()` function built into C++ for use on linux systems.

system("rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -database coke_can -sdf -model coke_can3 -y 2.2 -x -0.3");

---

Originally posted by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) with karma: 113 on 2015-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to dynamically spawn a model from your code is to call the `spawn_model` ROS service offered by gazebo_ros, which essentially is the same what the `spawn_model` node does internally. I.e. instead of running the `spawn_model` node, you call the `spawn_model` service.

You can see [here](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/hydro-devel/gazebo_msgs/srv/SpawnModel.srv) how the corresponding service interface is defined. Use `rosservice list` to find the correct name of the service instance while you have your Gazebo instance running.

Tutorials for writing a service client (which is very easy and similar to writing a ROS publisher) can be found here:
[C++ service client tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28c%2B%2B%29#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node)
[Python service client tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient%28python%29#rospy_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingServiceClient.Writing_the_Client_Node)

---

Originally posted by [timm](https://answers.ros.org/users/6556/timm/) with karma: 376 on 2015-04-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-04-15**:
I originally tried to use the `spawn_model` service. The thing is, the `spawn_model` wrapper node has the functionality of pulling the XML for the model from the online database, so I don't have to specify it manually when I create the srv object for calling the service. That is what I need.

**Comment by [Jordan9](https://answers.ros.org/users/22059/jordan9/) on 2015-04-16**:
Mmmkay, I can't accept this answer because it doesn't actually address the general question of whether it's possible to spawn a new ROS node from inside the code of another node.